# Adding the lib for usbbusif

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, driver

I am working on a kernel driver using the KMDF framework / template inside of VisualStudio 2019. While working on this I needed to use the GUID of `USB_BUS_INTERFACE_USBDI_GUID`. After looking into it, it appears that I needed to include `usbbusif.h` which did appear to work since it does contain that GUID but when I try to build my driver I get an `LINK2001 unresolved external symbol USB_BUS_INTERFACE_USBDI_GUID` error.

So my question is how can I solve this? For all similar linking errors I needed to go into my projects properties into the Linker section and then adding the lib into General and Input's Additional Dependencies section. But where and what is the name of the lib I need to include to fix this error?

Comment: See [the documentation about the DEFINE_GUID macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/including-guids-in-driver-code).